# Woocommerce Updating existing products using Import not working as expected for images column

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Wordpress version: 4.9.7
Woocommerce version: 3.4.3

I imported a product using Woocommerce Import method. First time my product images column has 3 images (separated by commas). This worked pretty well.

However, Later I decided to update the same product with only one image. I replaced images column with only one image. But when I am uploading the CSV in Woocommerce product importer ( Update existing products checkbox checked), still I could see the old images in Product gallery. How can I solve this issue?

After First Import (Images column has 3 images:
[After First Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecgr5.jpg)

After Update (Images column has 1 image):
[After Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxHS6.jpg)

Comment: Sounds like the data that you initially imported is still there. Importing new data won't remove the old data. Did you back up the database before importing the file? If you did you should revert back to the database before you uploaded anything and start again from scratch.

Comment: Technically, I am updating the old products. So, the data must be updated rather than creating new one